# cron job at certain time of day - what's the limit?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I'm after a little advice around using Cron jobs with PHP. My scenario is this:

I have a website with a large membership. Users have one or several URLS associated with their account. At midnight (or a certain time) I'd like to call a script which will query the websites for each user and update the database with the information it finds. Think of it as a sort of screen scraper service.

My question is around the stress of the server. I'll be testing this new feature on the shared server, but ultimately I will be moving to a dedicated server.

So if the c.5000 membership have 2 URLS each - that's 10,000 websites it would query. What do people think is the best way to do this? Have a cron job that runs the first 500 members - then 10 minutes later run the next 500 etc etc...

or is there some magic which I've not heard of which might help!?

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 2):

cron is a great tool to use for basic concepts like this. However, it scales poorly, as you've surmised! Look into job processing tools, like the open-source (and multi-language) Gearman:

http://gearman.org/

This should be a more robust system for the task at hand.

Comment: As others have pointed out, there's a learning curve to it. I love cron, trust me - I use it for many simple repeated/scheduled tasks. But it sounds like you'll need a real job scheduler at some point, and learning it while you have time and no pressing need is a better solution than learning it after you've written 800 lines of custom error handling code in PHP. :) (If it sounds like I am speaking from experience...)

Answer (score 0):

I would schedule a script daily, let the script query the 10,000 websites just one after another.  Just one script that loops over all the websites and send a request and process the results one by one. For this kind of numbers there's no need make in any more difficult, imho.

Comment: thanks. Would this be scalable? I mean, should the service prove popular, one user may have 10, 20, 50 odd websites. I guess I'd need to think about charging to cover costs or something. Maybe just a server for churning away updates all day and another for the www.

Comment: You could try to just let the script run on 10,000 websites, see how long it takes. I don't think it will take that long. Make sure you create the script to run according to some parameters (ie starting id, number of websites, etc), so that in case that it does become popular and you will need more sophisticated stuff it will be possible with the least amount of effort.

Comment: This approach is definitely the most simple. It will also not scale and will require a lot of logic to check for errors, resume on errors, and so forth - all of which has been written for you in Gearman (which has a PHP extension).

Comment: @Kyle; you could very well be right, I'm not familiar with Gearman, I'm just thinking of how I would do this kind of stuff.

Comment: @Lex: I am in love with cron; don't get me wrong! It's just that error handling and scalability concerns get you writing tons of try/catch and custom functions/classes to handle these problems once you've decided that cron is the way to go, and while the learning curve of Gearman is steeper than cron (which is the beauty of cron in the first place, I'll readily admit), the benefits are too large to ignore. At some point the OP's website will NEED to use a job scheduler, and it's best to start when the tasks are medium-sized, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested already you could run the URL script all in one go sequentially. That's the simplest approach.

If that's not fast enough you could easily modify your cron script so that you can invoke it run on odd/even numbers. Run the script twice starting at midnight, once for odds, once for evens and as long as you don't exhaust any resources on the machine it should run twice as fast.

In terms of implementing this I would consider having the script accept two integer values which let you define the modulus and remainder. E.g. for odd even you define "2 0" and "2 1" which would result in something like `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id % 2 == 0` and `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id % 2 == 1` being executed against the SQL database. Using this approach it'd be very easy to configure any number of jobs to run in parallel.

gearmand is very powerful and I have used it on a number of projects but there's a bigger learning curve with it. I think the simple solution I suggested should get you by.

Comment: this seems to make sense - I'm just trying to understand it all. I'd have one script which as you said runs at 00:00. The frequency would be every 1 minute? Previously with Cron jobs I've just said to run every hour etc.

Comment: You'd start two cron scripts at midnight. One with `myscript 2 0` (evens) and the other as `myscript 2 1` (odds). They'd both run at the same time.